# Image width issue in IE

Tags: functions, images, css, post-thumbnails

For some reason images are being displayed as a thin line in IE 8 and earlier and i cannot work out why this could be. I'm using CSS to re-size the images for the homepage, the reason for me using CSS to re-size the images is because the thumbnails are being generated by Wordpress.

This is what it looks like in IE...

[image: IE8 and below - thin images]

How it looks in Firefox and all other browsers...

[image: Firefox and other major browsers]

The CSS i'm using to size the images...

```
.home .attachment-home-post-thumbnail {
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 125px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 140px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: With a link to the site I could probably work it out but pure CSS questions are off-topic per the [faq].

Comment: The thumbnails being generated by WordPress is no reason to use CSS for re-sizing. Re-sizing images on the client-side is highly inefficient.

Comment: The reason thumbnails are re-sized using CSS, is because i want the sizes to be exactly the same on the homepage and didn't want to hard-crop. So i guess there is a reason to use CSS for re-sizing afterall. If that wasn't enough, i wanted them to display in one specific size on the homepage, but their native sizes within the post.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to width: 100%; being applied by Wordpress to all images. The code below fixes this issue - i applied this only to IE 8 and lower, as these are the browsers that have issues with the code.

```
img.size-full, img.size-large, img.header-image, img.wp-post-image {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```